# Can I use Windows drivers on Ubuntu and is it legal to do so?

Tags: drivers, wireless, legal

What is the legitimacy of installing and using Windows drivers on Linux?

For example, I want to use Wi-Fi drivers that are made for Windows, not for Linux.

Can I still use them on my Ubuntu laptop since they are free, or is there a legal issue?

Comment: Not a legal issue, a technical one, you can not use Windows drivers in Ubuntu.

Comment: "wifi drivers for exemple they are made for windows not for linux," Almost every wireless device has a Linux-specific driver. All are free to use without any legal restriction. A very few use proprietary firmware that is free to use but not to copy. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Most wireless hardware will have Linux drivers, and those that don't may possibly use ndiswrapper around the Windows driver.

Comment: @ubfan1 ndiswrapper hasn't worked correctly in many years. I know of but one device that's rather old, that has no Linux-specific driver.

Comment: "I want to use Wi-Fi drivers that are made for Windows, not for Linux." Then you need to install Windows and forget about Linux. They are called Windows drivers for a reason ;-)